# jQuery, get Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Number] has no method 'apply'

Tags: javascript, jquery, apply, confirm

I am using a Jquery plugin "confirm" by Nadia Alramli. I added some feature in this plugin but get this kind error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Number] has no method 'apply' ", I checked and really cannot figure it out, please help...

```
    jQuery.fn.confirm = function(options) {
            options = jQuery.extend({
                msg: 'Are you sure?', stopAfter: 'never', wrapper: '<span></span>',
                eventType: 'click', dialogShow: 'show', dialogSpeed: '', timeout: 0,

                //**belows are what I added**
                wrapperLeft: 0, wrapperTop: 0,
                outerWrapper: '<span class="relative"></span>',
                mask: '<span class="confirmMask"></span>',
                //**aboves are what I added**

            }, options);
            options.stopAfter = options.stopAfter.toLowerCase();
            if (!options.stopAfter in ['never', 'once', 'ok', 'cancel']) {
                options.stopAfter = 'never';
            }
            options.buttons = jQuery.extend({
                ok: 'Yes', cancel: 'No', wrapper: '<a href="#"></a>', separator: '/'
            }, options.buttons);

            // Shortcut to eventType.
            var type = options.eventType;

            return this.each(function() {
                var target = this, $target = jQuery(target), timer;
                var saveHandlers = function() {
                    var events = jQuery._data(target, 'events'); //for jquery high version
                    if (!events && target.href) {
                        // No handlers but we have href
                        $target.bind('click', function() { document.location = target.href });
                        events = jQuery._data(target, 'events');
                    } else if (!events) {
                        // There are no handlers to save.
                        return;
                    }
                    target._handlers = new Array();
                    for (var i in events[type]) {
                        target._handlers.push(events[type][i]);
                    }
                }

                // Create ok button, and bind in to a click handler.
                var $ok = jQuery(options.buttons.wrapper).append(options.buttons.ok).click(function() {
                    // Check if timeout is set.
                    if (options.timeout != 0) {
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                    }
                    $target.unbind(type, handler);
                    //$target.show(); //no hide
                    $dialog.hide();
                    // Rebind the saved handlers.
                    if (target._handlers != undefined) {
                        jQuery.each(target._handlers, function() {
                            $target.click(this);
                        });
                    }
                    // Trigger click event.
                    $target.click();
                    if (options.stopAfter != 'ok' && options.stopAfter != 'once') {
                        $target.unbind(type);
                        // Rebind the confirmation handler.
                        $target.one(type, handler);
                    }
                    return false;
                })

                var $cancel = jQuery(options.buttons.wrapper).append(options.buttons.cancel).click(function() {
                    // Check if timeout is set.
                    if (options.timeout != 0) {
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                    }
                    if (options.stopAfter != 'cancel' && options.stopAfter != 'once') {
                        $target.one(type, handler);
                    }
                    //$target.show(); //no hide
                    $dialog.hide();
                    return false;
                });

                if (options.buttons.cls) {
                    $ok.addClass(options.buttons.cls);
                    $cancel.addClass(options.buttons.cls);
                }

                //**belows are what I added**
                var $mask = jQuery(options.mask);
                var $wrapper = jQuery(options.wrapper);
                //**aboves are what I added**

                var $dia = jQuery($wrapper).append(options.msg).append($ok).append(options.buttons.separator).append($cancel);
                var $dialog = jQuery(options.outerWrapper).append($mask).append($dia);

                var handler = function() {
                    //jQuery(this).hide(); //no hide

                    // Do this check because of a jQuery bug
                    if (options.dialogShow != 'show') {
                        $dialog.hide();
                    }

                    $dialog.insertBefore(this);

                    //**belows are what I added**
                    $mask.css({ width: document.body.scrollWidth,
                        height: document.body.scrollHeight,
                        top: -$mask.offset().top,
                        left: -$mask.offset().left
                    });
                    $wrapper.css({ top: options.wrapperTop, left: options.wrapperLeft });
                //**aboves are what I added**

                    // Display the dialog.
                    $dialog[options.dialogShow](options.dialogSpeed);
                    if (options.timeout != 0) {
                        // Set timeout
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                        timer = setTimeout(function() { $cancel.click(); $target.one(type, handler); }, options.timeout);
                    }
                    return false;
                };

                saveHandlers();
                $target.unbind(type);
                target._confirm = handler
                target._confirmEvent = type;
                $target.one(type, handler);
            });
}
```

Comment: A call to `apply()` doesn't appear anywhere in your code.

Comment: Where is this error happening? What does your JS console say?

Comment: @m59 the apply function is probably called by another jQuery function.

Comment: @jvse good point. Maybe he's calling a jQuery function on an object it shouldn't be used on...

Comment: Hi everyone, this is a jquery plugin, and I added some my own code to satisfy my need. it seems will call a function in jquery named: dispatch, and the error is in line 3061 "ret = ( (jQuery.event.special[ handleObj.origType ] || {}).handle || handleObj.handler ).apply( matched.elem, args );" said "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Number] has no method 'apply' ",  it seems that what I added in this plugin caused something wrong. If I remove all my code, this plugin will work just fine. so, it must be something wrong with my own code in this plugin, but I only added some outer wrapper...